# redirect fails in Passport js local strategy using Express

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am new to passport js. My Login redirect always fails for some reason and it ends up in failureRedirect.Below is the code snippet.
When I click on Login, as a response it redirects me back to Login page because failureRedirect is set to /login. There are no other error messages. 
Is there any way I can debug passport js or any other suggestions to solve the issue?

```js
$('#signin-button').click(function () {

var username = $('#signin-email').val();
var password = $('#signin-password').val();
var form = new FormData();
form.append("username", username);
form.append("password", password);
//alert ('email/pass:' + username + ", " + password);
var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "/login",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "ab1b08a7-1a77-97e9-1039-92479d10b68b"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": {"username": username,"password": password}
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
});
```

Route :

```
app.post('/login',passport.authenticate('local-login',
{            successRedirect : '/dashboard', 
            failureRedirect : '/login'
}));
```

Passport.js

```
 passport.use(
        'local-login',
        new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
},
        function(req, username, password, done) {               
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_name = ?",[username], function(err, rows){
                if (err)
                    return done(err);
                if (!rows.length) {
                    return done(null, false});
                }

                // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if (!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].password))
                    return done(null, false);     
                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, rows[0]);
            });
        })
    );
```

Comment: I think you may be opening yourself up to a sql injection with this code. Unless your sql module watches for sql injection. what if username had a sql statement in it ?

Comment: Can you also show your main express configuration code (where you're configuring all your middleware, etc)?

Comment: I could not figure out the problem. So I followed passport js tutorial step by step and recreated the application. Everything works fine now. Thank you guys for your response.